# naming parameters in ruby on rails using form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm trying to pass through some parameters using form_for in rails, how do I pass them so that they can be accessed in the controller like this: `params[:image]`? the start of my form_for tag looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@image, as: :image, url: create_image_path(current_user),  html: { multipart: true }, method: :post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Are there any problems using the [default `file_field`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) helpers? If so, how does your full code look, what error/problem are you seeing and what would you expect?

Comment: Tell me if my solution doesn't help you..And if does then make my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example wtih carrierwave

gem install carrierwave

```
rails g model Resume  attachment:string

rails g uploader attachment
```

**Add this in your model , controller and view **

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.

end



class ResumesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @resumes = Resume.all
   end

   def new
      @resume = Resume.new
   end

   def create
      @resume = Resume.new(resume_params)

      if @resume.save
         redirect_to resumes_path, notice: "The resume #{@resume.name} has been uploaded."
      else
         render "new"
      end

   end

   def destroy
      @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
      @resume.destroy
      redirect_to resumes_path, notice:  "The resume #{@resume.name} has been deleted."
   end

   private
      def resume_params
      params.require(:resume).permit( :attachment)
   end

end


<div class = "well">
   <%= form_for @resume, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```